# Adding 10-bit binary numbers

Tags: c, binary

I need to 2 strings (10-bit binary numbers). I's easy when i'm adding 1+0 0+0
But how I can modify this, to situation when i'll need to make 11-bit
like
1010101010+1111111111=11010101001

```
i = MAX+1;
    while( i!=0) {
        if ((str1[i - 1] == str2[i - 1]) && (str1[i - 1] == '0' )) {
            str3[i] = '0';
        }
        else if ((str1[i - 1] != str2[i - 1])) {
            str3[i] = '1';
        }
        else if ((str1[i - 1] == str2[i - 1]) && (str1[i - 1] == '1')) {
            str3[i] = '0';
        }
        i--;
    }
```

MAX=10

Comment: Implementing addition on binary strings is kind of odd.  Would it be acceptable to provide an answer that involves converting these strings to integers?  What would a good answer for you look like?

Comment: No, I can't use converting

Comment: You don't seem to be using a carry over. For ex: 11 + 11 = 110. Or maybe I'm not seeing it.

Comment: 1+1=0, with a carry of 1. Actually a carry must be added too. Compare every one of the 3 variables with 1, and sum it. Just like adding decimal numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what the requirements are, but I wrote a function that takes three strings, figures out their lengths using `strlen`, and then sets the third string equal to the sum of the first two.  Here is a program that adds the two 10-bit numbers you gave and prints the expected result of "11010101001".

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void binary_string_add(const char * a, const char * b, char * sum)
{
  size_t alen = strlen(a);
  size_t blen = strlen(b);
  size_t sumlen = strlen(sum);

  int carry = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sumlen; i++)
  {
    if (i < alen) { carry += a[alen - 1 - i] == '1'; }
    if (i < blen) { carry += b[blen - 1 - i] == '1'; }
    sum[sumlen - 1 - i] = '0' + (carry & 1);
    carry >>= 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  char str1[] = "1010101010";
  char str2[] = "1111111111";
  char str3[] = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

  binary_string_add(str1, str2, str3);
  printf("Sum: %s\n", str3);
}
```

By the way, each iteration of the loop actually implements a [1-bit adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)).

**Update:**  If you want an easier interface that allocates an output string for you of the appropriate length and returns it, this works:

```c
char * binary_string_add2(const char * a, const char * b)
{
  size_t alen = strlen(a);
  size_t blen = strlen(b);
  size_t sumlen = (alen > blen ? alen : blen) + 1;
  char * sum = malloc(sumlen + 1);
  if (sum == NULL) { /** Add error handling here. **/ }
  memset(sum, 'x', sumlen);
  sum[sumlen] = 0;
  binary_string_add(a, b, sum);
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Not to good. Imagine that you do not know how long the operands are and you need to create "xxxxxxxxxx" of the proper length

Comment: It sounds like the Anchr explicitly wants to add two 10-bit numbers and get an 11-bit result.  If that is not the case, Anchr should clarify what the requirements are.  Anyway, I provided a much more general thing that can work with input and output strings of any length, and you could easily add a wrapper around it that allocates memory for a new output string with the right length or something if that's what you need.

Comment: Anyway - calculate the end of the buffer in the function. Function should return something as well. For example to be used as a parameter of other functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ADDCHAR(c1,c2)  (((c1) == '1') + ((c2) == '1'))

char *add(char *res, const char *n1, const char *n2)
{
    size_t ln1 = strlen(n1);
    size_t ln2 = strlen(n2);
    char *resend = res + (ln2 > ln1 ? ln2 + 2 : ln1 + 2);
    unsigned rem = 0;

    *resend-- = 0;
    while(ln1 || ln2)
    {
        unsigned pres = rem + ADDCHAR(ln1 ? n1[ln1 - 1] : '0', ln2 ? n2[ln2 - 1] : '0');
        *resend-- = '0' + (pres & 1);
        rem = pres >> 1;
        ln1 -= !!ln1;
        ln2 -= !!ln2;
    }
    if(rem) *resend-- = '0' + rem;
    while(resend >= res) *resend-- = ' ';
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 0 ;
       
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10  ; i++){
    str3[i] = str1[i] + str2[i] + a ;
    if(str3[i] > 1){
        str3[i] %= 2 ;
        a = 1 ;
    }
    else{
        a = 0 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It looks like you've made a sincere attempt to contribute an answer, which is appreciated. But it also appears like you got a bit sloppy with your formatting. Can you review your answer and clean up your formatting? As it stands, this will only be of limited use to readers. While you're at it, please be sure to include an explanation.